# Why does isClick become false when button is not being clicked anymore?

Tags: c++, sfml

I am working on a button in SFML. `std::cout << isClick` prints `1` when my mouse is being clicked, but somehow `0` when I let go. I have not put that in my code.

button.cpp:

```cpp
bool Button::checkClick(sf::RenderWindow& window) {
    sf::Vector2i mousePos = sf::Mouse::getPosition(window);
    if (mousePos.x > pos.x
        && mousePos.x < pos.x + size.x
        && mousePos.y > pos.y
        && mousePos.y < pos.y + size.y) {
            if (sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Left)) {
                button.setFillColor(button_color_click);
                isClick = true;
            } else if (isClick == true) {
                isClick = false;
                return true;
            } else {
                button.setFillColor(button_color_hover);
            }
        } else {
            button.setFillColor(button_color);
        }
    std::cout << isClick;
    return false;
}
```

button.h:

```cpp
class Button {
    public:
        sf::Vector2f pos, size;
        sf::RectangleShape button;
        sf::Text text;
        bool isClick = false;

        sf::Color button_color, button_color_hover, button_color_click;

        Button(sf::Vector2f pos_, sf::Vector2f size_, std::string text_, sf::Font& font, float font_size, sf::Color button_color_, sf::Color button_color_hover_, sf::Color button_color_click_, sf::Color text_color, float outline, sf::Color outline_color);
        void draw(sf::RenderWindow& window);
        bool checkClick(sf::RenderWindow& window);
};
```

How I call it in main.cpp:

```cpp
if (newGameButton.checkClick(window)) {
    resetGame(window, status, ball, velocity, paddle1, paddle2);
    std::cout << "clicked\n";
}
```

Except it is not printing anything.

I want `isClick` to not return `false` once I let go.

**EDIT:** Every other line of code that involves button `newGameButton` and button class:

```cpp
void drawGameEnded(sf::RenderWindow& window, gameStatus& status, sf::Text& winningText, Button newGameButton, sf::CircleShape& ball, sf::Vector2f& velocity, sf::RectangleShape& paddle1, sf::RectangleShape& paddle2) {
    // change winning text    

    winningText.setString(status.winner ? "Player 1 Wins!" : "Player 2 Wins!");

    // update button

    if (newGameButton.checkClick(window)) {
        resetGame(window, status, ball, velocity, paddle1, paddle2);
        std::cout << "clicked\n";
    }

    // draw everything on screen
    
    window.clear();

    window.draw(winningText);
    newGameButton.draw(window);

    window.display();
}
```

Main loop:

```cpp
sf::Clock deltaTime;
gameStatus status;

while (window.isOpen())
{
    sf::Time dt = deltaTime.restart();
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();
    }

    if (!status.gameEnded) {
        drawGame(paddle1, paddle2, ball, velocity, dt, window, paddleSpeed, status);
        continue;
    }
    drawGameEnded(window, status, winningText, newGameButton, ball, velocity, paddle1, paddle2);

}
```

Initialising `newGameButton`:

```cpp
Button newGameButton(sf::Vector2f(400.f, 500.f), sf::Vector2f(400.f, 150.f), "New Game", droid_sans, 24.f, grey1, grey3, grey4, grey2, 10, grey2);
```

button.cpp (without `Button::checkClick()`):

```cpp
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "button.h"
#include <iostream>

Button::Button(sf::Vector2f pos_, sf::Vector2f size_, std::string text_, sf::Font& font, float font_size, sf::Color button_color_, sf::Color button_color_hover_, sf::Color button_color_click_, sf::Color text_color, float outline, sf::Color outline_color) {
    button.setPosition(pos_);
    button.setSize(size_);
    button.setFillColor(button_color_);
    button.setOutlineThickness(outline);
    button.setOutlineColor(outline_color);
    text.setFont(font);
    text.setCharacterSize(font_size);
    text.setString(text_);
    text.setFillColor(text_color);
    text.setPosition(pos_.x+(size_.x-text.getGlobalBounds().width)/2, pos_.y+(size_.y-text.getGlobalBounds().height)/2);
    pos = pos_;
    size = size_;
    button_color = button_color_;
    button_color_click = button_color_click_;
    button_color_hover = button_color_hover_;
}

void Button::draw(sf::RenderWindow& window) {
    window.draw(button);
    window.draw(text);
}
```

Comment: You said *'I have not put that in my code'*. I'm looking at the code and I see this `} else if (isClick == true) { isClick = false;`. I could easily be misunderstanding something, but it seems to me that you did put it in the code.

Comment: @john It is in the code, it is just never run because it can't be not clicking and `isClick` at the same time because somehow it is becoming false. I have also tried removing it but still the same output.

Comment: I think then you need to show more code, so people can better understand how the different pieces of your code fit together. Obviously variables don't change by themselves.

Comment: @john I have put some more code, I hope it helps.

Comment: I'm still confused about what it is that's not working and what it is that you want. Hopefully someone else will be able to help. I suggest you add more logging to your code so you can work out exactly what path it's taking and what the variable values are.

Comment: I guess I will just reset the game as soon as it clicks instead of when I let go. If anyone else has a good answer I will use it.

Comment: No, I've found the bug. I'm writing an answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the problem is that you are **copying** your button object, and modifying the copy. That's why the `isClick` variable seems to go back to `false`.

The copy happens here

```
void drawGameEnded(sf::RenderWindow& window, gameStatus& status, sf::Text& winningText, 
    Button newGameButton, sf::CircleShape& ball, sf::Vector2f& velocity, 
    sf::RectangleShape& paddle1, sf::RectangleShape& paddle2) {
```

It should be pass by reference to avoid the copy

```
void drawGameEnded(sf::RenderWindow& window, gameStatus& status, sf::Text& winningText, 
    Button& newGameButton, sf::CircleShape& ball, sf::Vector2f& velocity, 
    sf::RectangleShape& paddle1, sf::RectangleShape& paddle2) {
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I don't know how I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

In below condition, you are not returning anything from the method:

```
if (sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Left)) {
            button.setFillColor(button_color_click);
            isClick = true;                
        }
```

As a result, execution continues till the last statement i.e. `"return false"`.

Try adding return statement as below.

```
if (sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Left)) {
            button.setFillColor(button_color_click);
            isClick = true;
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: It is supposed to return `false`. I want it to return `true` as soon as I let go of the mouse, which is what the `else if (isClick == true)` statement is for.